# Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I know I should use paramaterized queries for this but it is an internal tool for inserting text files. Anyone see the error for the Unclosed quote? Weird, I ran it in SQL Server 2014 and it ran successfullyafter I dropped " and the ; at the end of the Values assign. But in Visual studio in my project it needs the ";
 Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                string query = "Insert into BluStar(ProductID,Manufacturer,SKU,BlueStarSKU,MSRP,RoughSummary,COST,Inventory,Weight,CAT4th,CAT1st,CAT2nd,CAT3rd,ProductName,Genre,ProductName2,RougherSummary,Cat_4th,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13) Values('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][10].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][11].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][12].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][13].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][14].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][15].ToString() +
                "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][16].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][17].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][18].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][19].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][20].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][21].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][22].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][23].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][24].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][25].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][26].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][27].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][28].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][29].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][30].ToString() + "')";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Here is the code I have to convert from console to MVC to read the csv file.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head>
   <title>read file insert into data base</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@Import namespace=System.Data %>
<%@Import namespace=System.Data.SqlClient %>
<% 

System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("/testdata/test.csv");
string line;
while(sr.Peek() != -1)
{
   line = sr.ReadLine();
   String[] parts = line.Split('\t');
   Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(parts[3]) + "<br/>");

string conn = "";
string Manu;
string sku;
Decimal msrp = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[4]);  
conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString(); 
SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn); 
objsqlconn.Open(); 
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ScanSource(Manufacture,SKU,MSRP) Values(@Manu, @sku,@msrp)", objsqlconn);
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manu",parts[1]);
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku",parts[3]);
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msrp",msrp);
objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use your debugger to look at what is in `query` after it is populated.  If needed, copy the SQL into SSMS and run it there.  Then, read up on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Do you have an apostrophe in the strings?

Comment: "Internal" or not parameterizing your queries is the way to go. Also, when writing queries don't be scared to add a space (or even a new line) after each column. Being able to read this is critical. If I was going to debug this the first thing I would do is format the code so it is legible. Then I would very likely move this to a stored proc, add some validation, error handling and properly handle my connection object.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Fix that, and your syntax error will go away.

Comment: Can't find an apostrophe. @Ghost. Ran it in Sql and it ran fine but without the "; at the end of the query. Visual studio doesn't like it without the "; at the end. I know about sql injection but its an internal tool, not for live production.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Sean Lange

Comment: Looking at this code again I would suggest you might want to look at table valued parameters. There is no need to run a separate insert for each row in your table. Instead create a user defined table type that represents your rows in your DataTable. Then pass the entire set to sql server and do this as a single insert statement.

Comment: Just being lazy. I see its a simple syntax error but couldn't find it. Will have to rewrite this as a parameterized query. Thanks for the advice everyone.

Comment: @Sean Lange Hey Sean. I am new to programming and I am having difficulty redoing the above code with a  parameterized query. Could you offer any assistance?

Comment: Very hard to find simple structure for this to return a dt (DataTable).

Comment: Where is `ds.Tables[0]` coming from? If you're querying one table to turn around and do an `INSERT` on another, you should be able to do this entirely in SQL and save the round trip.

Comment: @alroc Are you referring to calling a stored procedure? I could do that, but I don't know how to select a file from a directory then automatically reference that file in SQL Server 2014 stored proc. Our data people want to simply open the tool, select the new csv file, hit a upload button, and import the file into Sql Server.

Comment: I'm not talking about a stored procedure specifically; I'm saying that if you're moving data from table A to table B, you can do it entirely in one query. But that's not what you're doing, so it's a moot point. Why not use an SSIS package to load the tables? You can execute those from a C# program (client), and it should be faster than tons of inserts. Also, look at using BCP to do bulk inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables need some serious help too. You have things like Field1, Field2...this is awful. Consider what happens when you need to add Field14. You will have to update everything everywhere. This kind of thing belongs in a child table.

I am NOT going to post a full solution here because there are a lot of columns and I have no idea what datatypes anything is.

This should get you started.

```
Insert into BluStar
(
    ProductID
    , Manufacturer
    , SKU
    , BlueStarSKU
    , MSRP
    , RoughSummary
    , COST
    , Inventory
    , Weight
    , CAT4th
    , CAT1st
    , CAT2nd
    , CAT3rd
    , ProductName
    , Genre
    , ProductName2
    , RougherSummary
    , Cat_4th
    , Field1
    , Field2
    , Field3
    , Field4
    , Field5
    , Field6
    , Field7
    , Field8
    , Field9
    , Field10
    , Field11
    , Field12
    , Field13
) 
Values
(
    @ProductID
    , @Manufacturer
    , @SKU
    , @BlueStarSKU
    , @MSRP
    , @RoughSummary
    , @COST
    , @Inventory
    , @Weight
    , @CAT4th
    , @CAT1st
    , @CAT2nd
    , @CAT3rd
    , @ProductName
    , @Genre
    , @ProductName2
    , @RougherSummary
    , @Cat_4th
    , @Field1
    , @Field2
    , @Field3
    , @Field4
    , @Field5
    , @Field6
    , @Field7
    , @Field8
    , @Field9
    , @Field10
    , @Field11
    , @Field12
    , @Field13
)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
```

Comment: I know. The project has 2 files sent every week. My task is to make a tool to insert the files be it tab, or pipe delimited. Sucks. I really appreciate the help. @Sean Lange

Comment: These fields headers are the same for every file the data guys receive every week. There wont be additional fields added.

Comment: If the format is consistent then I would still recommend using a table valued parameter to a procedure instead of looping through a dataset row by row. You create a user defined table type with the columns. Then you create a procedure that receives it as a parameter. From the dotnet side you simply pass your datatable. It doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange I'm a novice at this. Getting better everyday. can't find any current good books for Database access, Sql Server using MVC. Just tutorials that have to be manipulated. No true structural breakdown of the components to effectively read data into a table so I can make my own custom code. Especially csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using a table valued parameter. Now you have to realize I can't test this so it might need a little tweaking. Also I have no idea what datatypes you have in your table so you will need to adjust those.

Before you can use a table valued parameter you have to create the type. Here is how you might go about that.

```
CREATE TYPE BluStar AS TABLE
(
    ProductID int
    , Manufacturer varchar(10)
    , SKU varchar(10)
    , BlueStarSKU varchar(10)
    , MSRP varchar(10)
    , RoughSummary varchar(10)
    , COST varchar(10)
    , Inventory varchar(10)
    , Weight varchar(10)
    , CAT4th varchar(10)
    , CAT1st varchar(10)
    , CAT2nd varchar(10)
    , CAT3rd varchar(10)
    , ProductName varchar(10)
    , Genre varchar(10)
    , ProductName2 varchar(10)
    , RougherSummary varchar(10)
    , Cat_4th varchar(10)
    , Field1 varchar(10)
    , Field2 varchar(10)
    , Field3 varchar(10)
    , Field4 varchar(10)
    , Field5 varchar(10)
    , Field6 varchar(10)
    , Field7 varchar(10)
    , Field8 varchar(10)
    , Field9 varchar(10)
    , Field10 varchar(10)
    , Field11 varchar(10)
    , Field12 varchar(10)
    , Field13 varchar(10)
)
```

Now we have our own datatype in sql server that mimics what our actual table will look like. This probably seems a bit overkill but remember we are going to be passing in a whole set of rows instead of doing a separate insert for each and every row. Here is what our procedure would look like.

```
create procedure BluStar_Insert
(
    @BluStar BluStar READONLY
) as

    Insert into BluStar
    (
        ProductID
        , Manufacturer
        , SKU
        , BlueStarSKU
        , MSRP
        , RoughSummary
        , COST
        , Inventory
        , Weight
        , CAT4th
        , CAT1st
        , CAT2nd
        , CAT3rd
        , ProductName
        , Genre
        , ProductName2
        , RougherSummary
        , Cat_4th
        , Field1
        , Field2
        , Field3
        , Field4
        , Field5
        , Field6
        , Field7
        , Field8
        , Field9
        , Field10
        , Field11
        , Field12
        , Field13
    ) 
    select 
        ProductID
        , Manufacturer
        , SKU
        , BlueStarSKU
        , MSRP
        , RoughSummary
        , COST
        , Inventory
        , Weight
        , CAT4th
        , CAT1st
        , CAT2nd
        , CAT3rd
        , ProductName
        , Genre
        , ProductName2
        , RougherSummary
        , Cat_4th
        , Field1
        , Field2
        , Field3
        , Field4
        , Field5
        , Field6
        , Field7
        , Field8
        , Field9
        , Field10
        , Field11
        , Field12
        , Field13
    from @BluStar
```

That's all fine and dandy but without an example of this from dotnet it doesn't help much. This is intended to be the ENTIRE dotnet code. No more loops.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = SqlCommand("BluStar_Insert", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BluStar", ds.Tables[0]));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome. Thank you @Sean Lange

Comment: I just added the code I was trying to change to MVC from aspx to insert the csv file.